# If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

Tags: keyerror

This Code is not running,How can I fix it?

```
correlations_data = data.corr()['score'].sort_values()
correlations_data
```

It is showing this kind of error,

```
KeyError   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805             except TypeError:
   3806
```

## If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'score'

I have tried this,but it is also showing another error

correlations_data = data['score'].corr(['Order'])
correlations_data